# how can i make this printf print the method without formatting errors

Tags: java, printf

How can I make this printf properly output the method without errors in the printf code. Teacher did not go over the formatting just a simple example.

```
public static void printReportHeadings(int [] employeeId, int [] dependents, double [] hours, double [] payRate )
{
    System.out.println("                             ABC PayRoll System ");
    System.out.println(" EmployeeId " + " Gross Pay " + " Federal Tax " + " State Tax " + " Net Pay ");

    for (int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        float gross;
        double federal =0.0;
        double state = 0.0;
        double net = 0.0;

        gross = (float)(hours[i]*payRate[i]);
        federal = .2 * (gross-(dependents[i]*38.46));
        state = .032*gross; 
        net = gross - (federal+state);


        System.out.printf("%-15d %.01f % 15f%n", employeeId[i], gross, federal  , state, net) ;


    }
```

Comment: Why is this a C and a C++ question?!

Comment: just new to this website and needed some more tags it said

Answer (score 0):

You've got three placeholders and five things you're trying to bind to those placeholders.

Observe:

```
 System.out.printf("%-15d %.01f % 15f%n", employeeId[i], gross, federal, state, net);
```

`%-15d`, `%.01f`, and `%15f` are all placeholders for an integer, an two floating-point numerals respectively.  The other two - `state` and `net` - simply don't have a placeholder.

Adding a couple more placeholders for a floating point type will fix your issue:

```
System.out.printf("%-15d %.01f %15f %10f %10f%n", employeeId[i], gross, federal, state, net);
```

Comment: @user3503932 The `Java: The Complete Reference` book by Herbert Schlidt would be an excellent book to add to the book shelf and/or electronic book library.  Anytime I am using Java and especially any of the Generics, the book is reviewed.  It is already on the ninth edition: [Java The Complete Reference 9/E \[Paperback\]](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Complete-Reference-Herbert-Schildt/dp/0071808558)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i appreciate the help and the quick response!